# How to change domain name instead of ip address for 3CX Phone System

Tags: windows, iis, server, 3cx

Instead of access the server via these URLs:

- http://privateipaddress/management/MainForm.wgx
- http://publicipaddress/management/MainForm.wgx.

I want to access it like:

- http://subdomain.mydomain.com.sg/management/MainForm.wgx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open your IIS Manager
2. Right click on the 3CX website and select "edit bindings"
3. Click Add
4. Enter the domain name you want to use and a port
5. Click OK

This will make the website accept it, you have to make sure the DNS record is set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In Forward Lookup Zone of DNS Manager, I added new host (A) record and points to private/public IP Address.